# Wrong scopes prompted on after google login on my site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api, gmail-api, google-signin

I am using 3rd party google login form our react js website. It is working fine.
After that, I am enabling YouTube and google drive service on my two different pages for this I passed the scopes parameter with **gapi.client.init()** function but when I clicked on **connect YouTube** button google prompted me YouTube scopes as well as google drive scopes. The same problem I am facing on **connect google drive** page. 
All I want is it to show YouTube scope/permission on **connect YouTube** page and google drive scope/permission on **connect google drive** page.

Here is code:

```js
window.gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'clientId': REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SCOPE_YOUTUBE,
    'access_type': 'offline',
    'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest']
})  

window.gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'clientId': REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SCOPE_DRIVE,
    'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest']
})
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Can you provide a link to the 3rd party library you are using?

Comment: Thanks, Aerials
yes sure, I am using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps and follow  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs docs

Comment: It seems you are initializing both clients on window load. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: both the code is written on different files that's why I need to initialize it.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue without the context around those functions. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)